# question about the Borel function and measurable space

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Problem:
Let ${f_n}$ be a sequence of Borel functions on a measurable space. Show that:\

(a) $\sigma(f_1,f_2,\cdots)=\sigma(\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}\sigma(f_j)))=\sigma(\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}\sigma(f_1,f_2,\cdots,f_j)));$\

(b) $\sigma(lim sup_n f_n)\subset\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \sigma(f_n,f_{n+1},\cdots)$.\

My question: what is $\sigma(f_1,f_2,\cdots)$? I only know  $\sigma(A_1,A_2,\cdots)$, when $A_1, A_2,\cdots)$ are the sets.

Answer (score 0):

For any collection of real valued funcions $(f_i)_i$ on a set $X$, the notation $\sigma ((f_i)_i)$ stands for the smallest sigma algebra with respect to which each $f_i$ is measurable. (This sigma algebra always exists). a) follows easily from the definition. For b) note that $\lim \sup_n f_n =\lim \sup_n f_{k+n}$ for each $k$. can you complete the proof of b) using this?.